# Setting up SSL in Apache2 with backend docker app

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, docker, reverse-proxy, cors

I'm running Ubuntu server (18.04) on an Azure VM, with Apache2 (2.4.29). I have a backend app running in docker on the same host that is called by my site. This works easy enough without SSL. I added my SSL certificate, and a static page loads fine over https (so the certificate is valid). When I add the page that calls my app (listening on host port 8080) I get an error:

> GET https://myhost.com:8080/api/fetchService net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Since my app in the container isnt setup for SSL, how do I configure Apache2 to interact with the local container without SSL?

virtual host conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin me@email.com
        ServerName myhost.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/myhost.com/public_html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

    SSLProxyEngine on

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass *:8080/ http://myhost.com:8080/

    ProxyPassReverse *:8080/ http://myhost.com:8080/

    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myhost.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myhost.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
 </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You already did. But you are bypassing Apache by calling the container directly.

Comment: Ok, so is there anyway to serve up the web page via Apache that interacts with the backend docker service (which doesnt support ssl)?

Comment: You already did that. Just use `https://myhost.com/api/fetchService` instead of `https://myhost.com:8080/api/fetchService`.

Comment: So i test by going to my html page in the apache virtual host: `https://myhost.com/index.html`. That page calls my docker app at `https://myhost.com:8080/api/fetchService`

Answer (score 0):

Posting for anyone else with the same problem. I ended up creating a 2nd virtual host for the reverse proxy.

so site1 -> for the apache webpage with ssl,

site2 -> reverse proxy to terminate ssl for container service.
Then copied orig ssl virtual host file and adjusted for new virtual host 8443:

comment out Document Root (e.g. # Document Root)

```
<Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/ flushpackets=on
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/ 
</Location>
```

Also added a 2nd listening port in ports.conf (e.g. 8443) and enabled site.
a2ensite reverse-ssl.conf
systemctl restart apache2

good to go!